# Getting the values of a dynamically created control inside Telerik:RadGrid

Tags: dynamic, telerik, radgrid

I have a telerik RadGrid to which I am adding columns dynamically on click of a button. The Code is as follows :

```
 private void AddColumns()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtParMaintenanceListHeaderData = (DataTable)Session["ParMaintenanceListHeaderData"];
            foreach (DataColumn dc in dtParMaintenanceListHeaderData.Columns)
            {
                dc.ReadOnly = false;
            }
            if (!dtParMaintenanceListHeaderData.Columns.Contains("parComboDataField"))
                dtParMaintenanceListHeaderData.Columns.Add("parComboDataField", typeof(string));
            dtParMaintenanceListHeaderData.AcceptChanges();
            foreach (DataRow drEachRow in dtParMaintenanceListHeaderData.Rows)
            {
                string cusCombo = drEachRow["cusfstnam"].ToString() + " - " + drEachRow["cuslstnam"].ToString();
                string parCombo = drEachRow["parcod"].ToString() + " - " + drEachRow["pardsc"].ToString();
                drEachRow["parComboDataField"] = cusCombo + " " + parCombo;
                GridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn();
                string templateColumnName = cusCombo + " - " + parCombo;
                templateColumn.ItemTemplate = new RadGridTemplate(templateColumnName);
                templateColumn.HeaderText = templateColumnName;
                templateColumn.DataField = "parqty";
                templateColumn.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                templateColumn.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                templateColumn.HeaderStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(60);
                templateColumn.HeaderStyle.Wrap = true;

                this.radgridParListItems.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(templateColumn);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {


        }
    }
```

The above method is called on click of a button.

In each of the columns added I am adding a textbox as follows :

```
#region Namespaces used
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using Telerik.Web.UI;
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for RadGridTemplate
/// </summary>
public class RadGridTemplate : ITemplate
{
    protected LiteralControl lControl;
    protected TextBox textBox;
    private string colname;
    public RadGridTemplate(string cName)
    {
        colname = cName;
    }
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {

        textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.ID = container.ID + "txtParQty";
        textBox.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
        container.Controls.Add(textBox);
         textBox.Text = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[textBox.UniqueID];
    }



}
```

Now there is another button,"Save" which when clicked upon will have to fetch the data from all the textboxes in the dynamically added controls. The trouble is :

On post back all the controls are cleared and re-created so their values are null.

How do I capture the values of all the textboxes in a row.

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiate the template columns on init as explained in the telerik docs [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdprogrammaticcreation.html), you should be able to keep their state steady on posbacks and fetch the data from the textboxes looping through the grid rows.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the solution for the use of other users who are all facing same problem.

To avoid recreation of dynamic controls in radgrid we have to call the set **EnableColumnsViewState**="**false**" in MasterTableView of the grid. It worked for me.

Regards,

Nathiya Rajendran.